# jQuery / Ajax Add Class to an LI not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery / Ajax Add Class to an LI not working. Trying to add the 'open' class to a LI, that opens my 'floating cart' area when an item has been added to the cart. However, the 'open' class just. won't. apply. Not sure why.

I'm also using the Bootstrap framework, and jQuery.

My Code is:

```
function ShoppingCartAddAJAX(formElement, productNumber) {
    formElement = $(formElement);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dmiajax.aspx?request=ShoppingCartAddAJAX",
        data: formElement.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Status == "WishListSuccess") {
                var url = "productslist.aspx?listName=" + response.listName + "&listType=" + response.listType;
                $(location).attr('href', url)
            } else if (response.Status == "Success") {
                if (response.Status == "Success") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "dmiajax.aspx?request=FloatingCart&extra=" + rnd(),
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#floating').addClass('open');
                            var floatingCart = $("ul.dropdown-menu.topcartopen");
                            if (floatingCart.length == 0) {
                                floatingCart = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu topcart open"></ul>').insertBefore("#floating-cart");
                                floatingCart.hoverIntent({
                                    over: function () {},
                                    timeout: 200,
                                    out: function () {
                                        $(this).stop(true, true).filter(":visible").hide("drop", {
                                            direction: "down"
                                        })
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            floatingCart.html(response);
                            $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
                            var floatingCartTbody = floatingCart.find("tbody");
                            floatingCartTbody.find("tr").filter(":last").effect("highlight", {
                                color: "#B3B3B3"
                            }, 3500);
                            floatingCart.fadeIn()
                        }
                    });
                    if (response.CartItemCount) {
                        if (response.CartItemCount == "0") {
                            $("a.cart-tools-total").html("Shopping Cart<span class=\"label label-orange font14\">0</span> - $0.00")
                        } else {
                            $("a.cart-tools-total").html("Shopping Cart <span class=\"label label-orange font14\"> " + response.CartItemCount + " Item(s)  </span> - " + response.CartItemTotal + " <b class=\"caret\"></b>")
                        }
                    }
                    formElement.find("select option").attr("selected", false);
                    formElement.find("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
                    formElement.find("input:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
                    formElement.find("input:text").val("");
                    if (formElement.find(".personalization-toggle").length > 0) {
                        formElement.find(".person-options").hide()
                    }
                    if (formElement.find(".attribute-wrap.trait").length > 0) {
                        formElement.find(".stock-wrap").remove()
                    }
                } else if (response.Error) {
                    alert(response.Error)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The line where I'm tring to add it to the LI is:

```
$('#floating').addClass('open');
```

The LI is:

```
<li id="floating" class="dropdown hover carticon cart">
```

The LI's ID is floating, I figured that'd add the class of 'open' to it. NOPE. For some reason, just not happening.

And, just for the sake of including it, the live environment is here: http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/

Comment: are there any errors/warning?

Comment: I think your function does too many things and should be split up in smaller chunks.

Comment: All your add to cart links seem to be firing a page reload and not hitting the ajax function. Where are you calling ShoppingCartAddAJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
 $('#floating').attr("class", "open");
```

Comment: Just tried it, is up at the link I provided. Doesn't add the class. :(

Comment: Try putting an alert before this line as _alert($('#floating').html())_ and see what comes out?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your ajax request. It maybe is getting an error:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "dmiajax.aspx?request=FloatingCart&extra=" + rnd(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#floating').addClass('open');
                        var floatingCart = $("ul.dropdown-menu.topcartopen");
                        if (floatingCart.length == 0) {
                            floatingCart = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu topcart open"></ul>').insertBefore("#floating-cart");
                            floatingCart.hoverIntent({
                                over: function () {},
                                timeout: 200,
                                out: function () {
                                    $(this).stop(true, true).filter(":visible").hide("drop", {
                                        direction: "down"
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        floatingCart.html(response);
                        $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
                        var floatingCartTbody = floatingCart.find("tbody");
                        floatingCartTbody.find("tr").filter(":last").effect("highlight", {
                            color: "#B3B3B3"
                        }, 3500);
                        floatingCart.fadeIn()
                    }
                    error: function(objAjax,state,exception){
                    console.log('exception: '+exception+'. State: '+state);
                    },
                });
```

Then, you will be able to check (at Firebug or other app) if your request is working right.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not correctly selecting the #floating element. Sometimes the element is not visible with only the ID and you must be a little more specific with the selectors.

We would need to see exactly the source for the rendered page to be sure what to put, but try doing this:

Add a button onto the page that you can use to test if you found the correct selector:

```
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Tester Click">
```

Next, add this javascript/jquery code and -- one at a time -- comment the test selector that failed, and uncomment the next attempt:

```
$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var test = $("#floating");
    //var test = $("li #floating");
    //var test = $("ul li #floating");
    //var test = $("ul > li #floating");

    if ( test.length > 0 ) {
        alert('Found this: ' + test.attr('id') );
    }
});
```

---

Once you are certain that you have the correct selector, then your original code -- using the correct selector -- should work:

```
$('#the > correctSelector').addClass('open');
```

---

Note: the above code uses jQuery, so ensure you are including the jQuery library on the page (usually between the `<head>` tags, like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I don't understand. How can I be any more specific than selecting the ID?

Comment: @user1879703 I can't think of a way to explain it. You are right: the #idname should be directly accessible in the DOM, but sometimes it isn't -- you have to get a little more specific.  TRY adding an ID to the parent elements and see if the TEST CODE I suggested can detect **them**. *It is simple code, yes? You can easily run a few tests and see if I am on the right track.* Because you have access to teh source and I don't, I must ask you to try these things for me and report back if they don't help. Then we think up something else -- but this is something I stumbled across several times.

Comment: I'm trying out the code, but console keeps saying there's unexpected ; and unexpected }, kinda odd. The code itself seemed really straight forward.

Comment: Ah, the test.attr('id'); line needed an ending )

Anyways, tried them all, none worked.

Comment: Sorry for the missing paren. Can you post the markup (source?) for the rendered page?  Did you try adding ID attrs to some of the parent elements and try the same test with *them*? Can you tell us the full DOM traversal hierarchy back to the document object for the #floating `<li>` element?

Comment: Sure thing. The code leading up to #floating is:

    <div class="pull-right">
            <div id="floating-cart">
              <ul class="nav topcart pull-left">
                <li id="floating" class="dropdown hover carticon cart">
                </li>       
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

I did try:

    var test = $("#floating.dropdown.hover.carticon.cart");

And:

    var test = $("li#floating.dropdown.hover.carticon.cart");


*Edit* Ok, apparently I have no idea how to make the code into code syntax in comments. I apologize.

Comment: Great - and what's above that? By the way, do all those elements exist originally in the DOM; are any of them injected after page load?  Try this: (1) `var test = $('#floating-cart');` and this: `var test = $('.pull-right');` -- but you wont get an attr('id') value for that, so change the alert to: `alert('Found this: ' + test.attr('class') );`  (use backticks for code)

Comment: Excellent. I took your jsFiddle and added a "Click Me" button and the test code, and [you can see that it's working]((http://jsfiddle.net/AuZYy/1/), so now we must figure out why it's not working in the $.ajax() success function.  Is the jsFiddle code originally part of the DOM, or *is it injected?*, or how is it being rendered?

Comment: You should also look at using [the new Promises interface](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html) for your AJAX code.

Comment: Ha, I found what the issue was. I had to wrap the JS you gave me in document.ready, bah. So #floating works in the alert, and it says "floating" in the alert.

So now it looks like:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    alert( $('#floating').attr('id') );
});
});
</script>

Comment: If it works in the alert, then you should now be able to select it in your AJAX. `Is the function containing your AJAX code called from with a document.ready function?` The function itself need not be within document.ready (although it doesn't hurt for everything to be inside it) but it cannot be called before the document is ready otherwise some of the elements won't exist yet and it will quietly die.